# Determine Mongoose findByIdAndUpdate() error type

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, http-status-code-404

Re. mongoose `findByIdAndUpdate():` How to determine proper error status code that whether id was not found (404) or passed data was invalid (422)?

Like alternatively we can use `model.findById()` first to determine 404 and then can use `model.update()` to determine 422.

Comment: You can't do it with `findByIdAndUpdate()`, you need to use `findById()` instead

Comment: Okay and also we can't differentiate it from 500?

Comment: Yes, you can not